# loading image in UITableViewCell asynchronously

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, grand-central-dispatch

What is the super very easy way to load the image in the UITableViewCell asynchronously say given a imageURL without having to subclassing the UITableViewCell, i.e: standard UITableViewCell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I know is to use SDWebImage library. Here is a link that explains how to utilize the SDWebImage library to load avatars asynchronously.

SDWebImage is an extension to the ImageView. Here is the usage:

```
// load the avatar using SDWebImage
    [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:tweet.profileImageUrl]
                   placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"grad_001.png"]];
```

And here is the referenced article:

[Implementing Twitter Search](http://highoncoding.com/Articles/814_Implementing_Twitter_Search_iOS_App_Using_AFNetworking__UITableView_and_MBProgressHUD.aspx)

Comment: I am talking about standard UITableViewCell

Comment: @xonegirlz The standard UITableViewCell also has an imageView. The SDWebImage simply extends the imageView. SDWebImage uses Categories to extend UIImageView.

Comment: This library, it doesn't handle a problem that an image may load afterwards, when the corresponding cell went out of screen, and because of reusing thing has already got another image associated with it. Or does it?

Answer (score 1):

In your .m, include the objective c runtime:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>
```

At the top of your @implementation section, define a static constant for use below:

```
static char * const myIndexPathAssociationKey = "";
```

In your cellForRowAtIndexPath, add the following code:

```
// Store a reference to the current cell that will enable the image to be associated with the correct  
// cell, when the image subsequently loaded asynchronously. Without this, the image may be mis-applied
// to a cell that has been dequeued and reused for other content, during rapid scrolling. 
objc_setAssociatedObject(cell,
                         myIndexPathAssociationKey,
                         indexPath,
                         OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);

// Load the image on a high priority background queue using Grand Central Dispatch.
// Can change priority by replacing HIGH with DEFAULT or LOW if desired.
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    UIImage *image = ... // Obtain your image here.

    // Code to actually update the cell once the image is obtained must be run on the main queue.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSIndexPath *cellIndexPath = (NSIndexPath *)objc_getAssociatedObject(cell, myIndexPathAssociationKey);
        if ([indexPath isEqual:cellIndexPath]) {
        // Only set cell image if the cell currently being displayed is the one that actually required this image.
        // Prevents reused cells from receiving images back from rendering that were requested for that cell in a previous life.
            [cell setImage:image];
        }
    });
}];
```

Finally, for supporting best performance when rapidly scrolling on older devices you may want to load the most recently requested images first... for that, see [this thread for  asynchronously loading cell images using a last-in first-out stack and GCD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7567827/last-in-first-out-stack-with-gcd).

Comment: but this ends up with EXC_BAD_ACCESS in line "if ([indexPath isEqual:cellIndexPath]) {" any clues?

Comment: fixed, had OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN instead of OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN in objc_setAssociatedObject