# How to build my cells inside a thread from a delegate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, cocoa-touch

I have this tableView and I want to build the cells in a custom way.
The way I do it is by adding subviews to the cell.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell=[[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    else
    {
        UIImageView* img=[UIImage imageNamed:@"abc.png"];
        [cell addSubview:img];    

        //processing the final cell takes time!
    }
    return cell;
}
```

But, since some jittery frame rate is affecting the responsiveness of the table, I'd like to pass all this creation of the cell into a thread. so I want to put an image of some sort, for the meantime, and once finished, the thread would update `cell` to be the final cell.

Is this a normal approach?

If so, how do I update the cell from the thread?

Do I need to define all variables as __block? before going into the thread?

Comment: is your image size is big? You can't update a cell from a thread. You have to preform this on main thread but still you can do any manipulation in background thread and just call the update on main thread.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8087010/loading-image-in-uitableviewcell-asynchronously

Comment: Create new XIB and add drag UITableViewCell  to it. Then you customize.That's the best way

Comment: Looking at your code you are adding the sub image view each time the cell is recycled. Why do you not do that just once when you instantiate the cell?

Answer (score 1):

> since some jittery frame rate is affecting the responsiveness of the table, I'd like to pass all this creation of the cell into a thread.

The vast majority of UIKit, which includes `UITableViewCell`, *isn't* thread safe. From Apple's documentation:

> For the most part, UIKit classes should be used only from an application’s main thread. This is particularly true for classes derived from UIResponder or that involve manipulating your application’s user interface in any way.

...only a few drawing and graphics context methods in `UIKit` are thread safe. It's a really bad idea to create your cells on a secondary thread. You don't want to be doing this.

There's a lot of material out there are ways to efficiently create and draw cells into table views - as someone has pointed out in the comments, you seem to be adding a `UIImageView` not at cell creation, but on re-use. This means your cells are going to have many, many image views being constantly added to them. This is obviously not a good idea.

A better idea is to create a `UITableViewCell` subclass that already contains the views you're going to need, or to add them at creation and access them via view tags.

Comment: UIKit isn't just not thread safe, UIKit is "drive-off-a-cliff-and-take-your-app-with-it" not thread safe.

Comment: I wouldn't go that far: drawing (be it strings, images, and graphics contexts) is explicitly thread safe from iOS 4 onwards. I agree that if you don't know what you're doing it's a recipe for disaster, and the majority of the framework remains main-thread only.

Comment: I would argue that none of those are actually part of UIKit. NSString is in foundation, UIImage is just an opaque wrapper around a data structure (either actual data, or a CGImage context, and is still not background-thread safe for UIKit operations), and graphics contexts are Core Animation (which is extremely background thread friendly), Core Graphics, and Core Image.

Comment: @lxt, when the cell creation is done, I can call update from the main thread, keeping it all thread safe, no?

Comment: @Ted - no, alloc/init'ing your `UITableViewCells` on a secondary thread is a very, very bad idea. I'm confident your problems are stemming from how you're adding a new image view *every* time the cell is recycled.

Comment: I have completely forgot to mention this. I AM using tags to reuse my views. My question is, how do I make the thread update the cell? I know cell is a UIView subclass. I think I will take the subclassing approach. So when the cell finishes to render, I would like to call something to set the UIView of the resulting cell to that of the cell image which is inside the table. basically this is what I am after