# How to go back to the first viewController in a complex scenario?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uiviewcontroller, popviewcontroller

I have the following layout of view controllers:

```
loginViewController -> tabBarViewController -> navigationViewController -> mainTableViewController -> logoutViewController.
                                            \
                                             --> navigationViewController -> secondaryTableViewController
```

If the user successfully logs in he goes to the first tab of the tabBarViewController which is itself the first viewController (the mainTableViewController) from a navigationViewController. Consider that this mainTableViewController shows several options, each one leading to its own viewController, being the logoutViewController one of the options.

In the logoutView i have a button to logout (cool uh?) and if logout succeeds I want to go back to the loginViewController.

I tried calling:

```
 [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

from the logoutViewController but nothing happens. I searched other similar questions but most of them suggests the use of popToRootViewControllerAnimated. I don't think it's that simple since I have a navigationController pushed from a tabBarController pushed from a viewController. What's the best way of doing this?

I hope it's not too confusing. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps I could store the loginViewController in a property of the tabBarController and use [self popToViewController:tabBarController.loginViewController] ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume the path is stored in some LiFo way; why don't you just Pop till the count = 1?

Comment: You mean calling popViewController and counting the returned array in a loop or something?

Comment: I don't have a concrete example, more a general programming reference. if you store your path in a Stack and do: Push loginViewController, Push tabBarViewController, Push navigationviewcontroller. If you Check the Stack's count, it will list 3. So, var ThisWillBeTheLoginController; while(Stack.Count > 0) ThisWillbeTheLoginController = Stack.Pop(); this should leave you with the loginViewController. Not sure how it would translate to ObjectiveC, but this pattern should be programmable in basically any language. Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7567827/last-in-first-out-stack-with-gcd