# How do you use async data to load NSTableView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, asynchronous, nstableview

I am fairly new to `Cocoa/Objective-C` so hopefully I'm just missing something.  It seems like this should be a fairly common situation.  This is all for a Mac application.

I have a `NSTableView` and it's delegate implements

```
-(NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)table viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
```

and

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView
```

The problem that I have is that the data that I am loading into the column is gathered via the asynchronous calls of a web service and the delegate methods of `NSStreamDelegate`.  I obviously can't return my column view at this point because I don't have the data yet to set it up correctly.

I have tried using the following code but since it's on the main thread it seems to lock it up on occasion.

```
...
NSDate *loopUntil = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.1];
while (!callDone && [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:loopUntil])
    loopUntil = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.1];

return rslt;
```

Has anyone else had to deal with this situation?

Thanks!

Comment: While this question (and answers):  http://stackoverflow.com/q/7567827/937822  are for the iPhone, it provides some **very** good information on doing this.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this, but I think you should be able to create an empty array (or dictionary, whatever you need to structure your data), and when the app first opens your table view will be empty (but i don't think it will crash).  When your data gets downloaded, add it to that empty array and call reloadData on your table view.