# Any simple tutorial to load custom objects asynchronous on uitableview cells while scrolling

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, asynchronous

I am trying to find a simple tutorial for inserting custom objects asynchronous on uitableview cells while scrolling because my uitableview does not scroll nicely and smoothly. I have searched but i only have found about images asynchronous loading not helpful. I have an uiview that needs to be loaded asynchronous. Too much processing work is needed before the object loads as a result scrolling is not smooth.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: here is a good question that covers this:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/7567827/937822

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not as hard as it seems. There is only one caveat. You must know the height of your cell even when it is not fully loaded.

If the tableView has a constant row height, then set tableView.rowHeight. If you need to determine row height on the fly use UITableViewDelegate's `–tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` callback.

Then in `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` dequeue a cell, set it to some initial state, kick off a NSOperation or a GCD block, and finally return the cell that you have reset.

In the NSOperation or CCG block you will perform the work you need, then call back into the main thread to set the values into the cell. This is the essence of async cell loading.

---

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // dequeue a cell

    // Reset the cell
    cell.imageView.image = nil;
    cell.textLabel.text = nil;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = nil;

    // Use gcd
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("blah blah replace me blah", 0);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{ 

        // Do work in the background

        UIImage *image       = value1;
        NSString *text       = value2;
        NSString *detailText = value3;

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ 
            // Back to main thread to set cell properties.
            if ([tableView indexPathForCell:cell].row == indexPath.row) {
                cell.imageView.image      = image;
                cell.textLabel.text       = text;
                cell.detailTextLabel.text = detailText;
            }
        });//end
    });//end
    dispatch_release(queue);

    // Return the reset cell
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering Jeffery. If you could provide a simple example i would be grateful.

Comment: I added a GCD example of `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: Thank you! Please tell me if i am right...The code in the   dispatch_async block will execute and will do the work in the background and then the dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue() will update the cell properties on main thread. My question is about return cell when this piece of code will execute? It will wait for the dispatch to finish? This is where i am getting confused. Because if there is no wait then i will get a cell with nothing on it and after the dispatch finishes then i get the updated properties. What will happen when i scroll up or down?

Comment: It will initially load an empty cell. After the dispatch is complete it will populate data into the cell (which will refresh automatically).  Cells will be retained by the block until the block is done. If the cell goes off the screen, then no big deal. The data will be updated on a cell that isn't shown.

NOTE: I updated my example to keep data from previous dispatches from being inserted into reused cells. It assumes there is only one section. If you have multiple sections to your table view, you will need a more complex check.

Comment: ok i got it i think so! Thank you again for your reply you are really helpful. So if i have to update not the cell properties but a custom view with an uiwebview,an uilabel and uiimageview i have to create the objects in the cellforrowatindexpath like this UIwebview *webview=nil; , UILabel *label=nil; etc. as you did cell.imageView.image = nil; cell.textLabel.text = nil; cell.detailTextLabel.text = nil; . Then i will have to do [cell.contentview addsubview:webview] etc... at the  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue() . Am i right?

Comment: The basic idea holds. Return an empty view right away. Setup an NSOperation or a GCD block to do the work. When you are done processing, go back to the main thread to update the UI. **Always update the UI in the main thread!**

As a final note: You may need to call -setNeedsLayout after making changes to a custom view.

Comment: Thanks i will try all your advices and see what happens. Thanks so much!

Comment: Unfortunately it is not working as expected. Still scrolling is not nice. I will post code in another and see if anyone could help me.